# Can you create an array from an array in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Edit: By print array I mean put the array onto a range in a sheet :)

I am using the following code on a table in excel with VBA. This combines rows with matching sales rep. Below is the source table. This is loaded into an array. [image: Source table before running code]

After running the below code the rows are combined and I null out the rows that were combined. My challenge is to print certain columns and only print the non null rows. To accomplish this I was trying to loop through the array and create another array with just the non null rows.

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues2()
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim rowcount As Long
Dim i As Variant
Dim colcount As Long

arr2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("APPLE").Range
rowcount = UBound(arr2, 1)
colcount = UBound(arr2, 2)
For i = rowcount To 2 Step -1


               If arr2(i, 3) = arr2(i - 1, 3) Then
arr2(i - 1, 6) = arr2(i - 1, 6) + arr2(i, 6)

For k = 1 To colcount
               arr2(i, k) = Null 'this loop is probably not required i can probably just use the first column
              
               Next k
               End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Ultimately I wanted to print just the non null rows and just Columns 3,2,and 6. The best way I thought was to create an array with non null rows
[image: Array After Running Code]

Comment: What do you mean by "print an array"?

Comment: I should have clarified that. Ultimately I want to save the arrays as a CSV. However I haven't seen a clean way to do that. Instead I want to "print" to a range and than create a CSV from that sheet.  @FaneDuru

Print as in put the array into a range.

Comment: You are totalling the unit cost is that intended ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. it is intended. I am trying total the cost for duplicate items (meaning matching rep). @CDP1802

Comment: OK but it would be more usual to total the total costs column 7 G

Comment: @CDP1802 this isn't real data I can't post the real data from work. This Is just a sample table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array for the results with the same number of rows as the data array. Scan down the data rows and at each change of value in column C increment a row counter for the results array . Dump the used part of the results using resize.

update - include headers

```vb
Sub mergeCategoryValues2()

    Dim arr2 As Variant, arOut As Variant
    Dim rowcount As Long, colcount As Long
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, v
    
    arr2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("APPLE").Range
    rowcount = UBound(arr2, 1)
    colcount = UBound(arr2, 2)
    
    ReDim arOut(1 To rowcount, 1 To 3)
    
    For i = 1 To rowcount
        If arr2(i, 3) = v Then
            arOut(k, 3) = arOut(k, 3) + arr2(i, 6)
        Else
            k = k + 1
            v = arr2(i, 3) ' compare with following rows
            arOut(k, 1) = arr2(i, 2)
            arOut(k, 2) = arr2(i, 3)
            arOut(k, 3) = arr2(i, 6)
        End If
    Next i
    
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(k, 3).Value2 = arOut
    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

Comment: That works incredibly well thank you! Are you able to explain a little more how it works with the if statement?

Comment: @Manuel The If is the same as your code, if the col C is the same as the previous col C then add to the existing row in the output array. If it isn't (else) then move to a new row with k=k+1 and create a new entry.

Comment: How does this line work  
 Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(k, 3).Value2 = arOut
I have never seen resize before.

Comment: @Manuel If k was 4 then `Range("A2").Resize(k, 3) `would be the same as `Range("A2:C5")`, it just expands the range by 4 rows, 3 columns.

Comment: is there a reason you changed the for loop direction? I had it stepping for rowcount to 2 step -1.
Again thank you so much for your help! I am very new to arrays im trying to understand them better

Comment: @Manuel Jut so the result came out in same same order as the data. You normally scan upwards when deleting rows

Comment: EDIT: Just used a goto. Probably bad practice but it works

is there a simple way to keep the headers? I can do it by making k = 1 at the beginning and than manually setting them but I was curious if it could be incorporated into the main loop.

Comment: @Manuel Ok - see update

Comment: @Manuel Are you able to add some comments? If not no worries i just cant wrap my head around how it works. And it works well!

Comment: @Manuel it starts with i at row 1 when v is blank so the if is false and row 1 (the header) gets added to the array and v is set to column C. When ever the column C value does not match v then a new entry is added to the array and v is updated.